# Multiple switches/FET's on a boost controller

Tags: boost

I'm new to DC-DC converters and I am trying to design a 500W ~12V step up to 50V power supply. I've been looking into boost converters and controllers and I think I need to go with a controller to have FET's that can handle that amount of power. I also believe if I use multiple converters in parallel I will need to synchronize their frequencies. Is it instead possible to use a single boost controller and multiple switch-inductor pairs? If not, is the best idea just to use multiple identical boost controller circuits and synchronize their clocks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you making one for a hobby project, or 100,000+ at work?

Comment: Q1: WHY do you need several? ||  You'll need about 50A - that's doable in one unit but a serious task . Q2: Why 12V Q3: why 500Watt  Q4 Why not buy one.

Comment: Use a forward converter not boost.

Comment: This is a personal hobby Q1: Several to keep price lower, as I imagine a single, powerful circuit is more than a few smaller ones. Q2: 12V minimum for automotive battery. Q3: This power supply is for an audio amplifier project and below 500W is my target power. Q4: As a project, skill building and learning.